# UITextView address selection inside UIView

Tags: uiview, swift2, interface-builder, uitextview, xcode7

I have a `TableViewController` in which I have a custom `UITableViewCell` called `TableViewCell.` Inside this cell I have the following: `UITextView` `UIImage` `UILabel.` The `UITextView` displays an address, so I have enabled address detection. It was working fine until I put all the objects inside a `UIView` so I could set a nice border inside the cell. Now, the address detection is no longer working. How do I keep the `UITextView` inside the `UIView` and also have address detection enabled?

Thanks in advance! (Comment for down votes)